# How to use multiple identifies in Page Object Factory

Tags: selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

Can anyone please help me to figure out how to use multiple identifiers in Page Object factory for below example:

```
@FindBy(how = How.NAME, using = "sex" And how = How.Value, using = "Male")
```

Note: Above is just an example, I know we can handle radio button in a different ways.

I was able to do this using XPath, but I could not find any documentation on using multiple identifiers in single find by.

Please give me a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FindBy` receives a locator like `findElement`

```
@FindBy(how = How.Name, using = "sex")
WebElement element
```

Is the equivalent of

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("sex"));
```

This means you can give an `Xpath` locator to the `FindBy` annotation

```
@FindBy(how = How.Xpath, using = "//*[@name='sex' and @value='Male']")
```